# Server to server messaging using signalr

Tags: asp.net, subdomain, signalr

Can anyone tell me how can we send server to server message with signalR?

I am creating chat application for that I used sub domain concept as there was problem in opening multiple concurrent connections with signalr. But using subdomain concept, chat is not implemented properly as it does not send message to connection opened from other subdomain. Can any one suggest me solution that how can we send messages to and from server in signalR?

I have already tried to implement centalized approach to store and use the connectionID but not worked.

Comment: there is no way where we can send message from server to server. I found only way where messages are send from server to client

Comment: SignalR allows bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available.
what do you mean by server to server?

Comment: I have used sub domain concepts so there is more than one hub class. So is there any way I can send message to all hub classes but all are at different domains